# Remove decimal places from varchar(32) result

Tags: varchar, sqlcommand

I'm using SQL and windows batch script to download inventory from our POS and then upload it to a 3rd party platform. The file is successfully downloading and uploading, but the 3rd party platform is quite finicky on formatting. Specifically, it won't accept decimal place for the column titled "Quantity".

I've searched and tried various different approaches but can't seem to find one that works. The tricky aspect to this sql is that i had to use a join in order to create a title row and I'm using the format varchar(32) I've posted my sql below, any suggestions?

```
set nocount ON

SELECT CAST('sku' as VARCHAR(32)) AS sku, 
CAST('quantity' as VARCHAR(32)) AS quantity
UNION
SELECT CAST(IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS 
VARCHAR(32)) as sku, case when 
IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then 
CAST(IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL AS VARCHAR(32)) else 
CAST(0 as VARCHAR(32)) END as quantity
FROM IM_BARCOD INNER JOIN IM_INV ON 
IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO INNER 
JOIN IM_PRC ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = 
IM_PRC.ITEM_NO INNER JOIN 
IM_ITEM ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
UNION
SELECT CAST(IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS 
VARCHAR(32)) as sku, case when 
IM_INV_CELL.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then 
CAST(IM_INV_CELL.QTY_AVAIL AS VARCHAR(32)) 
else CAST (0 as VARCHAR (32)) END as 
quantity FROM IM_BARCOD INNER JOIN IM_PRC 
ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = IM_PRC.ITEM_NO INNER 
JOIN IM_INV_CELL ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = 
IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO AND 
IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR=IM_BARCOD.DIM_1_UPR 
AND IM_INV_CELL.DIM_2_UPR = 
IM_BARCOD.DIM_2_UPR AND 
IM_INV_CELL.DIM_3_UPR =IM_BARCOD.DIM_3_UPR 
INNER JOIN 
IM_ITEM ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = 
IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
```

Comment: Cast it to an integer before casting to a varchar in your SQL statement.

Comment: how would the formatting look for that? i.e. cast((value as (int)),as varchar(32))? am i following you correctly?

Comment: No. `CAST(CAST(Value as INT) AS VARCHAR(32))`

Comment: that did it, thank you!